# Does rebuilding a RAID change data?

Tags: raid, mdadm

[I've just restarted my computer which was building up a RAID5 for the first time.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9467/is-it-normal-that-mdadm-has-to-start-from-scratch-when-i-restart-my-computer-whil) This of course meant that my computer had to rebuild the whole thing from ground up.

Before I restarted the computer I've had already set up a file system, which cannot be found anymore.

So: Does building up the RAID (again) overwrite any information placed on the volume?

Comment: It would be useful to know what exactly you are trying to do.  For example, are you using LVM on top of RAID or the other way around?

Comment: I'm combining 3 disks directly into a RAID, so there's no LVM at this level. I was just wondering, if the re-rebuilding of the RAID was messing with the data I already put on the created raid.

Comment: Can you include the output of `/proc/mdstat` too?

Comment: @kees: http://pastebin.com/V67hQpxy, though I don't why that's important to the question.

Comment: Does `sudo blkid /dev/md0` say anything about that volume?

Comment: @kees: no, it doesn't. just a blank output.

Comment: Sounds like the LVM was lost. :( You may need to recreate it with `pvcreate`.

Comment: @kees: That's what I figured. Do you know why?

Comment: I assume that since the RAID wasn't done doing its initial build, when the system rebooted, if failed to reconstruct correctly. That is a guess, though, and sounds like a bug. :(

Answer (score 2):

It's best not to reboot your system until after the initial RAID sync has finished, but you should be able to create your LVM physical volumes (`pvcreate /dev/md0` etc). If you've already done this and they're not showing up, it's possible that on restart the system did not auto-start your RAID due to it being out of sync. If you RAID is running correctly, you should be able to manually restart your LVM with `sudo vgchange -a y` at which point the LVs should be visible again with `sudo lvs`.

Comment: I've learned that the hard way. :) The command is `vgchange -a y`, but that didn't work.